# Merge typescript promises

Tags: typescript

Look at this typescript code:

```
async function my_function(arg: string): Promise<string> 
{  
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api.php?args=" + arg);
    ...
}

const items = ["100","98","35","400"];
let result = await Promise.all(items.map(my_function));
```

My API allows multiple arguments:

```
http://localhost:8000/api.php?args=100,98,35,400
```

Please not I can only change my_function's body code. I can't change this function signature.

Is there a way, inside my_function to access to other promises and to merge them into a single one ?

My goal is to launch a single fetch, without changing anything in the main code.

Comment: No. Change the main code properly.

Comment: I do not understand something. You do not want to change the main code, and you have said also that you do not want to change my_function. What are you allowed to change? You could rewrite the library that fetches the page and make it cache it... for example. Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, this function is used by other people and is doing a lot of stuff. I just want to keep it compatible.